# I am not sure if my htaccess conditions are going to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Can anybody tell me if my .htaccess conditions are valid? Or if there is any change/optimization needed?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(^.*Google.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /home/login/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Google.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [L,R=301]
```

I basically want every normal user to be redirected to /home/login/. If the user agent is or contains "Google", I want them to be redirected to /home/ only.

By the way, do I need "RewriteEngine on" at the top?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. yes, you do need to enable the rewriting engine so that the rules to get applied and 2. why don't you simply test your conditions and rules by making test requests with the headers you want to react to?

Comment: @arkascha thanks for the answer! Could you educate me more about making test requests? I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Making a http request is not that difficult. You can either use a scripting language (which ever you prefer) for that or a simple socket client which you feed by typing the (simple) http request (maybe copying it from a text where you prepare it). You will learn quite a lot on the way. There are browser extensions for such stuff these days too if you prefer a click tool.

Comment: Also obviously utilities like `curl` or `wget` are an option.